# Minimize complicated function for integer parameters using python?

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, pulp, mixed-integer-programming

I'm trying to find a way to optimize a guitar tuning for specific chords to fit one hand better, and I'm running into some trouble with the actual optimization part. Here's the start of my code, with my objective function defining a "score" associated with how well each chord would be played with one hand:

```
# defining chords by string and fret
d=np.array([5,7,7,4,5,np.nan])
bm=np.array([7,7,7,np.nan,5,7])
bm2=np.array([7,7,8,np.nan,6,7])
em=np.array([7,8,9,5,7,np.nan])
a7=np.array([5,5,6,5,0,np.nan])
d2=np.array([5,7,7,7,9,np.nan])
gm=np.array([6,8,7,8,10,np.nan])
g=np.array([7,8,7,np.nan,2,3])
a72=np.array([5,5,6,2,4,np.nan])
d3=np.array([5,7,7,7,5,np.nan])

#array of all chords
chords = np.array([d,bm, bm2, em, a7, d2, gm, g, a72, d3])

#objective function
def scorechord(o1, o2, o3, o4, o5):
    """
    shift strings 1-5 by amounts o1-o5
    positive number indicates string has been tuned down one half step
    returns a number associated with best chord structures for hand
    """
    newchords = np.empty([10,6])
    score=0
    for i in range(len(chords)):
        #shift notes on string by offset amount
        newchords[i][0]=chords[i][0]+o1
        newchords[i][1]=chords[i][1]+o2
        newchords[i][2]=chords[i][2]+o3
        newchords[i][3]=chords[i][3]+o4
        newchords[i][4]=chords[i][4]+o5
        newchords[i][5]=chords[i][5]
    for i in newchords:
        imin=np.nanmin(i)
        imax=np.nanmax(i)
        #want max/min fret close enough for hand
        if imax-imin>4 and imin!=0 and imax!=0:
            score+=100
        #best place to bar chord is lowest note
        if stats.mode(i[0])[0]!=imin:
            score+=10
        #want notes to overall be close together
        for j in range(5):
            if np.isnan(abs(i[j+1]-i[j]))==False:
                score+=abs(i[j+1]-i[j])
    return score
```

I'd use scipy optimize, but you can't restrict that to integer values; I tried PuLP instead, but ran into a problem passing the Lp variables into my function. From what I understand, you should normally explicitly write the function out instead of calling it to solve that problem, but I couldn't figure out how to do that with a function so complicated (and I'm also starting to worry that maybe this function isn't something PuLP will be able to solve even if I get it to work).

Here's that attempt:

```
Lp_prob = p.LpProblem('Problem', p.LpMinimize)

o1=p.LpVariable("o1", lowBound = -5, upBound = -5)
o2=p.LpVariable("o2", lowBound = -5, upBound = -5)
o3=p.LpVariable("o3", lowBound = -5, upBound = -5)
o4=p.LpVariable("o4", lowBound = -5, upBound = -5)
o5=p.LpVariable("o5", lowBound = -5, upBound = -5)

Lp_prob += scorechord(o1,o2,o3,o4,o5)
```

which returns the error "float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'LpAffineExpression'"

I'm at a loss as to how to proceed - is there another way to write out my function that PuLP will be able to understand it, or another package to consider trying? Or is it time to buckle down and write myself an optimization function by hand?